# In Flask, how can I unit test a WTF form?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I'm using [WTForms](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/wtforms/). When I run my test, I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: working outside of application context

Here's a simplified version of my test:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from forms.my_form import MyForm

class MyFormTest(TestCase):
    def test_expects_to_instantiate_new_form(self):
        form = MyForm()
        self.assertIsInstance(form, MyForm)
```

A simplified version of my form:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import HiddenField
from wtforms.validators import Required

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    hidden_field = HiddenField('Label will not be visible', [Required()])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To provide the required application context, I [manually pushed a context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#manually-push-a-context):

```
from unittest import TestCase
from forms.my_form import MyForm
from flask import Flask

class MyFormTest(TestCase):
    def test_expects_to_instantiate_new_form(self):
        # Arrange
        app = Flask(__name__)

        # Act
        with app.test_request_context('/'):
            form = MyForm()

        # Assert
        self.assertIsInstance(form, MyForm)
```